# How to read and pass multiple data from excel in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium4

My excel sheet has 2 columns Username& Password with different 5 records, I want to read and pass data from this excel and want to open 5 chrome browsers with these 5 users. How can this achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little something with ***Selenium, Java and JXL library*** to get you started,

```
try {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//file.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    
    WebDriver[] driver = new WebDriver[sheet.getRows()];

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//geckodriver");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "FFLogs.txt");
    
    for (int row = 1; row < sheet.getRows(); row++) {
        String username = sheet.getCell(0, row).getContents();
        String password = sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents();
        driver[row] = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver[row].manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver[row].get("https://www.google.com");
        driver[row].manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver[row].close();
    }
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
        driver[i].close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet (excel sheet) looks like,

[image]